# how to navigate the right page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery Mobile. I try to navigate to a page by using jquery but there is something wrong with the URL.

My code

```
 <a href="http://tom.hostxx.com/car.html" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-transition="pop">Car</a>
```

It loaded the page http://tom.hostxx.com/#http://tom.hostxx.com/car.html with blank content, in stead of http://tom.hostxx.com/car.html.

Can anyone explain? Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put a relative href?

I dunno where exactly is your page, but something like `href="car.html"`.

You should take a look at the [doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) and see their code.